# ¿Como se puede poner en un grafico dos variables en el eje Y?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

Estoy buscando como replicar un grafico de este modelo siento los T, T-1, T-2, etc, correspondiente a variables diferentes en una base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

##### Puedes utilizar stripplot de seaborn

import seaborn as sns

#Crear un dataframe data con los datos de tu base de datos

sns.stripplot(data=data, x="Margen de compra (log 10)", y="T", dodge=False, jitter=True)

Para personalizar más el gráfico puedes leer la documentación [completa](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).